# WebView2 download event is not firing - Windows forms application

Tags: path, download, webview2

I create windows forms application using WebView2 control, in there I add DownloadStarting event for select the downloading path to the user but unfortunately DownloadStarting event not firing.

```
private async void InitBrowser()
    {
        var environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, @"C:\Temp", null);
        webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment);
        webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
        webView.Source = new Uri("myurl");
        
    }
private void WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting;
        
    }
private void CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting1(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        downloadOperation = e.DownloadOperation;
        e.Handled = true;
        e.ResultFilePath = Savefile();
    }
```

Comment: Your event handler name in the code that registeres for the event doesn't match the method declaration (DownloadStarting**1** versus DownloadStarting). Is that a problem? Also, when the user runs your app what causes the download? And, does the download actually happen but the event isn't raised, or the download doesn't occur and the event isn't raised?